# If adjectives denote functions of type <<e,t>,<e,t>>, then what denotation of *be* will allow adjectives to appear in predicative position?

Tags: adjectives, formal-semantics, type-theory

Suppose [[*gray*]] = λf ∈ D<e,t> . [λx ∈ De . f(x) = 1 and x is gray]. Since this function is of type <<e,t>,<e,t>>, it would seem that sentences like *Julius is gray* are uninterpretable. My book asks me to come up with a denotation of *be* that would make *Julius is gray* interpretable. I get that it should be of type <<<e,t>,<e,t>>,<e,t>>, but i don't understand what the function should be. something like: λg ∈ D<<e,t>,<e,t>> . [λx . ???] maybe? Can someone give me a hint?

This is from the second exercise in section 4.3.2 of Heim and Kratzer's "Semantics in Generative Grammar".

Comment: What about for quantifiers that are conservative? I'm having trouble proving with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note 1: this sounds like a homework problem, so I'm going to try to give guidance toward the answer instead of just giving an answer outright.

Note 2: writing out the types of all the variables gets messy, so for the purposes of this answer, `x` is a variable of type e, `p` is a variable of type t, and `P` is a variable of type ⟨e,t⟩.

So I would write the denotation of *gray* in your model as `λP.λx.[P(x) ∧ gray(x)]`.

If you want to combine this with *be* through function application, then one is going to need to be applied to the other. You can either apply *be* to *gray*, or apply *gray* to *be*. What type would *be* need in order to apply *be* to *gray*? What about to apply *gray* to *be*?

The next question is, what do you want the result to look like? It seems like the logical denotation of *Julius is gray* should be `gray(julius)`, right?

Since we know the denotation of *Julius* is `julius`, then in order to get `gray(julius)`, the denotation of *is gray* should be `λx.gray(x)` (or just `gray` if you prefer).

So, what can be combined with `λP.λx.[P(x) ∧ gray(x)]` to create something equivalent to `λx.gray(x)`?

Direct hint 1:

> You're going to want to apply *gray* to *be*, not vice-versa. In other words, *gray* is the function and *be* is the argument. This means *be* should have a denotation of type ⟨e,t⟩.

Direct hint 2:

> `1 ∧ p` is logically equivalent to `p`.

My solution (but try solving it yourself before revealing this):

> `λx.1`